# authentication password required to download ubuntu application

Tags: grub2

I m using a wifi connection but when i m trying to download Ubuntu app from app store it is asking for some authentication password,i m also unable play downloaded video it asks for plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Software Center is asking for your administrative password (the one you use to log into Ubuntu), this for security reasons.

For the video you can install VLC, which will (usually) pull the required packages.

Comment: I m able to login  without any password so any other idea?i don't have plugin for audio video